# compute residual of $A/(\overline{z}-\overline{\lambda_1})$

Tags: complex-analysis, residue-calculus

Let $H(s)$ and $G(s)$ matrix valued functions in $s \in \mathbb{C}$ that are elements of $H^{p,m}_2$ (the set of all $p \times m$ matrix valued functions which follows particular analytic conditions (such that all what follows is well defined)).

This $H^{p,m}_2$ is a Hilbert space with improduct:
$<G,H> = 1/(2 \pi) \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \mbox{trace} \big( \overline{G(i \omega)} H(i \omega) \big) d \omega $

Now this last definition is equal to (by the residue theorem):
$<G,H>  = \sum_{ \lambda \mbox{ is pole} } \mbox{trace} ( \mbox{res}[ \overline{ G(\lambda)} H(\lambda)^T])$

Now take the particular case, that $G(s) = \dfrac{A}{s-\lambda_1}$ and $G(s) = \dfrac{B}{s-\lambda_2}$ for $A, B$ $p \times m$ matrices.

If I want to calculate $<G,H>$ , then I think the poles are $\lambda_1$ and $\lambda_2$

$\begin{eqnarray} 
<G,H>  & = & \sum_{ \lambda \mbox{ is pole} } \mbox{trace} ( \mbox{res}[ \overline{ G(\lambda)} H(\lambda)^T]) \\
& = & \mbox{trace} ( \mbox{res}[ \overline{ G(\lambda_1)} H(\lambda_1)^T]) + \mbox{trace} ( \mbox{res}[ \overline{ G(\lambda_2)} H(\lambda_2)^T]) \\
& = & \mbox{trace} ( \mbox{res}[ \overline{ G(\lambda_1)} H(\lambda_1)^T]) + \mbox{trace} \big( \dfrac{\overline{A} B^T}{s-\lambda_1} )
\end{eqnarray}$

How to calculate the first residual? I am struggling with the fact that there is complex conjugate.

thanks in advance

Comment: What does $\operatorname{Res}\frac1{\overline z-a}$ *mean*? The concept of residue is about analytic functions. Your function in differentiable nowhere.

Comment: I edited my question ( $a$ into $\overline{a}$). Does this make it clear or not?

Comment: @Koen Something is wrong here. May we take a look to the original problem?

Comment: Robert Z: is it more clear now?